# Counting number of primes $p$ less than $x$ with certain constraints on prime divisors of $p-1$ for Artin's Conjecture on primitive root

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

I was reading this [paper](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~murty/gupta-murty.pdf). There is a **Lemma 1** saying that for a fixed prime $q$ the cardinality of the set $\{p \leq x \mid (\frac{q}{p})=-1\}$ such that all odd prime divisors of $p-1$ are greater than $x^{\frac{1}{4}-\epsilon}$, is at least $\frac{cx}{\log^2x}$ where $c>0$ is some constant.

Its written in one of the cited source that it follows from **Theorem 1** of Rosser's sieve paper by Iwaneic (citation is mentioned in the original paper). But I don't understand how to do that.